Model Message at migration in django
My Model is like below.
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )

    USER_TYPE = (
        ('S', 'Super Admin'),
        ('A', 'Admin'),
        ('P', 'Patient'),
        ('D', 'Doctor'),
        ('U', 'User'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=USER_TYPE)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

I am getting message like below.
It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'password' to user without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.


You must have some user objects in the database, which have null value for the password field. Which stops the migration from applying since the field isnt nullable. What you can do to fix this is to go over your database entries and set passwords, or delete the users without passwords. Both approaches should fix your problem.

Thanks @Arif Rasim. I deleted user from auth_user table and tried to run python manage.py makemigrations. But I am getting above message again. Thanks.

Its a bad idea generally to delete a table in django manually, as the migrations lose track of the database. If you cant retrieve the deleted table I would recommend to create the db from scratch and run the migrations again. This error indicates that you have a user row in the db without the password column.
